# smbinning.gen undefined columns

Tags: r, binning

I'd like to apply results of smbinning to a new dataset using smbinning.gen

The new dataset works fine when I use randomly selection of records and all the same columns.  I get an "undefined columns" message when I apply smbinning.gen to a new file that has re-ordered columns -- but still the same column names as the one needed for smbinning.gen

I'd like to get around this problem, and see no tips elsewhere on it.  Is it smbinning?  Or, and I am willingto admit it, is it my R code?

```
    chileancredit.train=subset(chileancredit,FlagSample==1)
    result$ivtable
```

Cutpoint CntRec CntGood CntBad CntCumRec CntCumGood CntCumBad PctRec GoodRate BadRate
1    <= 17   1138     909    229      1138        909       229 0.2405   0.7988  0.2012
2    <= 30    621     530     91      1759       1439       320 0.1312   0.8535  0.1465
3    <= 63   1064     985     79      2823       2424       399 0.2249   0.9258  0.0742
4     > 63   1427    1377     50      4250       3801       449 0.3016   0.9650  0.0350
5  Missing    482     435     47      4732       4236       496 0.1019   0.9025  0.0975
6    Total   4732    4236    496        NA         NA        NA 1.0000   0.8952  0.1048
     Odds LnOdds     WoE     IV
1  3.9694 1.3786 -0.7662 0.1893
2  5.8242 1.7620 -0.3828 0.0223
3 12.4684 2.5232  0.3784 0.0277
4 27.5400 3.3156  1.1708 0.2626
5  9.2553 2.2252  0.0804 0.0006
6  8.5403 2.1448  0.0000 0.5025

As documented, I have no issues coming up:

```
chileancredit.train=subset(chileancredit,FlagSample==1)
result=smbinning(df=chileancredit.train,y="FlagGB",x="TOB",p=0.05) # Run and save result
chileancredit.train=
```

+   smbinning.gen(chileancredit.train,result,"gTOB") # Update training sample
    summary(chileancredit.train$gTOB)

00 Miss 01 <= 17 02 <= 30 03 <= 63  04 > 63 
     587     1724      716     1201     1572

But I noted the attribute col_id for results.  And if I take a subset with column in another order, the columns involved smbinning.gen gets an error.

```
result$col_id 
temp2 <- data.frame(TOB=chileancredit$TOB)
temp2 <- smbinning.gen(df=temp2, result, chrname="TEMP_BIN")
```

[1] 2
Error in factor(df[, ncol], labels = blab) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 1

In another situation (another file), moving columns around, I got error message

**Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , col_id) : undefined columns selected**
Here's the data on the two files.

> str(temp2)
>   'data.frame':   7702 obs. of  1 variable:
>    $ TOB: int  44 79 102 NA 109 183 172 76 136 171 ...
>   str(chileancredit.train$TOB)
>    int [1:5800] 44 79 102 NA 109 183 172 76 136 171 ...

Comment: Based on a comment from the package maintainer, the above error is due to the fact that smbinning operations on a positional column (col_id), and not a variable name.  So while a bit confusing, smbinning.gen is performing as designed.